# X depends on flutter_web_plugins any which doesn't exist (could not find package flutter_web_plugins at https://pub.dev), version solving failed

Tags: flutter, dart-pub

more info:

```
`pub get failed
command: "/usr/local/dev/tooling/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/dart __deprecated_pub --color --directory . get --example"
pub env: {
  "FLUTTER_ROOT": "/usr/local/dev/tooling/flutter",
  "PUB_ENVIRONMENT": "flutter_cli:get",
  "PUB_CACHE": "/Users/ziv_l/.pub-cache",
}
exit code: 69`
```

and in pubspec.lock file:

```
flutter_web_plugins:
    dependency: "direct main"
    description:
      name: flutter_web_plugins
      sha256: bb8dcba2b000b9230e5fbbd726eb8199fe9313ca1e317d080d4e26bb3a5ca5a2
      url: "https://pub.mpflutter.com"
    source: hosted
    version: "1.2.1"
```

could you please tell me how solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think your url in pubspec.lock file is wrong because all the plugins are hosted by pub.dev .so you should use 'https://pub.dev'.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

`flutter_web_plugins` is part of the core Flutter libraries, it should work having this in your `pubspec.yaml`:

```yaml
dependencies:
  # ...
  flutter_web_plugins:
    sdk: flutter
```

And your `pubspec.lock` will look like this:

```yaml
  flutter_web_plugins:
    dependency: "direct main"
    description: flutter
    source: sdk
    version: "0.0.0"
```